# Trying to fix badblocks on a Linux partion: futile?

Tags: partitioning, badblocks

I'm on Ubuntu Linux 20.04. Over the past couple of weeks I've been noticing some erratic behaviour, like shutting down unprompted and then later booting into initramfs.

I followed the instructions online to run fsck but I've had to do this more than once now. I ran badblocks and have a list of what seems a small number (37) bad blocks. The problem didn't end there though, and I am now running badblocks again after the same initramfs came up.

I'm a bit worried that this won't be the end of it and I'm thinking about next steps. I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21365916) from a few years ago, which basically suggests that if badblocks turns up anything non-zero, then I should think of investing in a new hard drive.

Does anybody have advice at this point? Am I doomed to needing a new hard drive?

I should add that when I tried `sudo smartctl -H /dev/sda5` the resulted I got was "PASSED". I'm wondering how to compare these two bits of information?

Comment: It is *futile* to bother with `badblocks` if you have a failing drive; have you explored the drive health??  ie. using its inbuilt SMART?  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)  as a failing drive will just get *worse* and *worse* until it's unusable & you're forced to replace it...

Comment: So I got a "PASSED," but I'm still waiting on another badblocks errors list?

Comment: "Am I doomed to needing a new hard drive?" - if your data is worth anything, yes, as as guiverc mentioned it can only get worse, possibly to the point of not being able to recover anything anymore; stop running badblocks as that may aggravate the situation further, clone what you can to a new hard drive (or dump a raw backup of the failing drive somewhere in the meantime) using ddrescue (if it gets stuck you may play with the -r option) and move on. I disagree with running badblocks being futile, as it's often the only real meaningful metric to, say, check on ssds health.